# Are practical experiences as valuable as academic research experiences?

Tags: graduate-admissions, teaching, cv, projects

I'm a non-U.S undergraduate Computer Science student and I want to get admission from an eminent U.S university for M.Sc./PHD.

In my experiences, there are lots of practical records. From about 10 teaching assistantships (well I call it practical in comparison to publishing papers for example) and holding programming workshops to doing valuable professional projects, for example a noticeable social networking website which is of course related to my field of study and the fields I'm interested to continue to study and do research in M.SC./PHD.

But I don't have any publications and my GPA is about 2.8/4.0 .

I'm afraid if my CV seems to be more "practical" than "academic" and maybe admission offices of eminent universities are looking for more academic prospective students.

1- Now what's your opinion about this situation and my chance to get admission from eminent U.S universities?
2- From an academic professor's point of view, which is more valuable for an undergraduate student: having publications or making such projects or teaching experiences?

Comment: In the fields I am familiar with, and for the PhD track, admission is based on a mix of GPA/GRE/your alma matter/name and prominence of your letter writers. TAships should help you get recommendations that can be more personalized (certainly with 10!); but don't matter much by themselves. Publications are absolutely not expected (in these fields), but obviously nice if you have them; practical experience might matter for CS (but not in the fields I know again). As your GPA is a little low, I'd consider going for a masters first, work really hard, then re-apply for a PhD.